# Regex for folders that start with variables

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to find folders that start with variables that are NOT case sensitive

```
var varname = ("BUI")
var stringMatch = "\\" + varname + "\\b";
if (FolderItems[i].name.match(stringMatch)) {
//do script
}
```

I find Regex pretty confusing, I know `varname = \\\BUI\\\b`, but what do I need to find a folder that begins with that variable? I'd like this to find a folder called `'Building_v02'`

Comment: your code says varname = ("BUI"), your text says varName = \\BUI\\b - which is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [JavaScript regexp syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), `^` is the anchor for the start of the string. Case insensitivity is indicated separately with the `i` flag:

```
var varname = "BUI";
var re = new RegExp("^" + varname, "i");
if (re.test(FolderItems[i].name)) {
    // do script
}
```

However, you should [escape the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) if it could contain any undesirable regexp metacharacter.

Also note that you may not have to use a regexp:

```
var varname = "BUI".toLowerCase();
if (FolderItems[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(varname) === 0) {
    // do script
}
```

To actually iterate over the array of items:

```
for (var i = 0; i < FolderItems.length; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (FolderItems[i].name.match("^[BUI]")) {
  //do script
 }
```

^ mean that the string should start with 'BUI'

Comment: Actually it means the string should start with either `B`, `U`, or `I`. For a string starting with `BUI` you'd have to to `^(BUI)` (capturing) or `^(?:BUI)` (non-capturing).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily try in your browsers console. I'd say that you're better of using `substring` when you're matching the start of a string.

```
var matchFor = "BUI";
var folders = ["Building_v02","Building_v03", "unmatched"];
folders.filter(function(folder){
     return folder.substring(0,3).toLowerCase()===(matchFor.toLowerCase());
  }).forEach(function(value){
     console.log(value)
  });
```

This will not work in older browsers unless you add filter and forEach, for example using [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#)

Comment: Modified your code: extracted search term into `matchFor` and using `toLowerCase()` as the OP wants to match case insensitive. *"[...] start with variables that are NOT case sensitive"*

Answer (score 0):

```
var varname = "BUI";
var stringMatch = '^' + varname + '\\b';

if ( FolderItems[i].name.match( RegExp( stringMatch, 'i' ) ) {
    //do script
}
```

You can pass a string to `match` as you were doing, but if you pass in a RegExp object you can supply a second argument, `i`, which indicates that you want a case-insensitive match.

[Regular Expressions MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)